# Actions in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controllers, action

When typing in my URL 
**SalaryFor/Microsoft/Balmer** 
i need to display salary for user with name Balmer
and if I type in URL 
**SalaryFor/Microsoft**
i need to display salary for all employee in Microsoft company

Is it possible?
because when I use this link 
**SalaryFor/Microsoft/Balmer** 
all works fine

```
public ActionResult Salary(string company, string person)
```

both company and person contains values

but this link does not work
**SalaryFor/Microsoft**

```
public ActionResult SalaryFor(string company, string person)
```

both values contains null

my route in global.asax is

```
    routes.MapRoute("Salary",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{company}/{position}",
                    new
                        {
                            controller = "Salary",
                            action = "SalaryFor",
                            company = "",
                            test = ""
                        });
```

O maybe I am making something wrong?
Thanks,
Alexander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map a second route.

```
routes.MapRoute("Salary2",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{company}",
                    new
                        {
                            controller = "Salary",
                            action = "SalaryFor",
                            company = ""
                        });
```